# List custom field values ​​in alphabetical order without repetition

Tags: custom-field, list, meta-value

The function below lists the custom fields as in this example:

- Frank Capra
- Alfred Hitchcock
- Woody Allen
- Woody Allen
- Frank Capra
- Pedro Almodóvar
- Pedro Almodóvar

I introduce the values ​​in alphabetical order and without repetition. Eg:

- Alfred Hitchcock
- Frank Capra
- Pedro Almodóvar
- Woody Allen

---

This is the code:

```
<?php
$movie_reviews = get_posts('numberposts=-1&orderby=post_name&order=ASC');
foreach($movie_reviews as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li>
<?php $director = get_post_meta($post->ID, "director", $single = true);
if($director !== '') {
echo $director;
} ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Is this possible? Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a custom SQL query:

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'director' ORDER BY meta_value;";
$directors = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

foreach( $directors as $director ) :
    echo $director->meta_value;
endforeach;
```

one thing to note here though is that since you're not querying the associated posts, you could get values that belong to unpublished posts, if that's a concern.

Comment: Thank you @Milo. The result was this (no space between items): `Alfred HitchcockFrank CapraPedro Almodóvar`. Another question: You can add link for each item? example: `<a href="/Alfred-Hitchcock/">Alfred Hitchcock</a>`.

Comment: @Milo provide the hard part.  From here you need to adapt his foreach loop to show the desired markup.

Comment: Hello @helgatheviking, I'm adapting my loop. Already solved the problem of spaces adding `<br>`: `echo $director->meta_value . '<br />';` It is possible to obtain items that start for example with the letter "a"?

Comment: Perfect @Milo. I'm adapting my loop, already added a link for each item, now just need to separate the results by letter order. I want to list only directors whose names begin with the letter "a". Any tips?

Comment: @MichaelWilliam Please ask one question per topic.

Comment: Thank you @Milo. Is possible to divide the results in two columns?